# Add debugging console to django error page

Tags: django, debugging, werkzeug, django-extensions

How can I access the console from the django error page?

When my template produces an error I want to be able to check out my variables/ query sets without having to go back and add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` to my views every time I want to get to the console from a running app.

Comment: werkzeug (http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) used to be able to do this.. haven't tried it lately though..

Comment: Use both https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions and werkzeug. Haven't tried it lately though... but I believe Django Extensions makes Werkzeug available so you don't have to put anything anywhere.

Comment: Hey @thebjorn and @'allcaps, can write an answer to the question? so other people can see it more easily, so that it helps more people

Comment: Just use a debugger like the one built into pycharm, if you run a django project in debug mode it catches the error and displays the current state of objects.

Comment: @BrianOcampo it's all nicely written up in the django-extensions documentation: http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runserver_plus.html

Comment: @allcaps thank you for the connection. i have posted the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pip3 install django-extensions
# add 'django-extensions' to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py
pip3 install werkzeug

python3 manage.py runserver_plus
```

Now when you get errors in the browser you can click on the little console button when you hover over the output. thanks @thebjorn and @allcaps for pointing me in the right direction

[image]

^ `>>>` is where you can write your own comands